# HikariCP behavior when no connection is available

Tags: java, hikaricp

I noticed that even when the database is down, so no connection is actually available in the pool, Hikari CP still waits for the connection timeout to expire before sending an exception to the client.

I agree this is desirable when the database is available, but in my case I would like for the pool not to wait before sending an exception when no connection is available.

The reason is that the database itself answers in less than 2ms , so I can handle thousands of transactions per second but when there is no connection available the pool will wait for a lot longer (the minimum acceptable timeout recommended being 250 ms) so I can no longer handle the throughput. On the other hand, my logic can work without the database for a period of time.

How should I manage this?

EDIT:

[This link](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1060) is almost what I want to achieve, minus the fact that I would prefer HikariCP to do this automatically, I shouldn't activate the suspend state.

Comment: Im currently facing the same issue, have you come to a solution regarding this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't remember well, but I think that in terms of Hikari, I used the 250ms timeout which was not great at all. On a different project than the one I asked this question for, I used Hystrix which lets you specify a timeout for a method and a fallback when the method is considered unavailable (for example, after some timeouts). This should also tackle Hikari's limitation.

Comment: i enabled JMX, and im looking at the total connections in the pool. If the total connections in the pool for data source drops to 0 it means there is a problem reaching the database and i throw an exception before calling getConnection() (that blocks for connectionTimeout period). Now before the totalConnections drop to 0 it takes some time (depends on the number of connections in the pool), because it has to call getConnection() and block and then invalidate and evict the connection from the pool. But after the pool is empty i can process the records from cache and skip db  read-through.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should introduce a counter somewhere in your application code and if the number of concurrent requests exceeds the value don't use database. It's hard to tell without knowing what you are dealing with e.g. read vs write.

As per [brettwooldridge comment regarding `connectionTimeout` property](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/547#issuecomment-171976129) lower timeout is unreliable due to thread scheduling, even when there are available connections:

> We can certainly consider a lower floor, but 125ms would be the absolute minimum.
>
> Both Windows and Linux have a default scheduler quantum of 20ms. If 16 threads are running on a 4-core CPU, a single thread may have to wait up to 80ms just to be allowed to run. If the pool has a vacancy due to, for example, the retirement of a connection at maxLifetime, this leaves precious little time to establish a connection to fill the slot without returning a spurious failure to the client.
>
> If careful consideration is not taken to ensure the CPU and scheduler are not oversaturated, running at a 125ms timeout, puts your application tier at risk of spurious failures even if the pool has available connections. For example, running 32 threads on a 4-core CPU can lead to thread starvations under load as long as 120ms -- very close to the edge.

Comment: Thanks, Karol, but my question was slightly different. The number of concurrent requests doesn't matter , and neither if it's read or write operations. I'm talking about the use case where the database is offline and I don't want the clients to wait for the timeout to expire when they need to acquire a new connection.